# How to get a value "10th" from jsonobject to java?

Tags: java, php, android, json

My php code is:

```
$query=mysql_query("select adm_num,firstname,dob,adm_date,address1,mothername,medium,fathername from students where adm_num ='".$_REQUEST["adm_num"]."'");
$get_classid = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("select class_id from students where adm_num = '".$_REQUEST["adm_num"]."'"));
$sql = mysql_query("select class as classname from school_classes where class_id=".$get_classid["class_id"]." and admin_id=1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
$output[]=$row;

}
 while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
$output[]=$row2;
}
$sql1 = mysql_query("select * from school_exams where admin_id=1");
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1))
{
$output[]=$row1;

}
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
```

My code is:

```
     String getclass;
     JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
    JSONObject json_data=null;

    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
        json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        getadmnno=json_data.getString("adm_num");
        getstudname=json_data.getString("firstname");
        getdob=json_data.getString("dob");
        getadmndate=json_data.getString("adm_date");
        getaddress=json_data.getString("address1");
        getfathername=json_data.getString("mothername");
        getmedium=json_data.getString("medium");
        getmothername=json_data.getString("fathername");
        getclassname=json_data.getString("class_id");
        admNo.setText(getadmnno);
        name.setText(getstudname); 
        dob.setText(getdob);
        admnDate.setText(getadmndate);
        address.setText(getaddress); 
        fatherName.setText(getfathername);
        medium.setText(getmedium);
        motherName.setText(getmothername);
        className.setText(getclassname);

    }
```

//The value i get in class_name is "10th", hence the problem.

the json output is like this:

`[{"adm_num":"1","firstname":"RAJESH","dob":"2011-12-19","adm_date":"0000-00-00","address1":"hyd","mothername":"shahid","medium":"English","fathername":"Mohanamma"},{"classname":"10th"},{"exam_id":"1","admin_id":"1","types":"Unit Test-1"},{"exam_id":"2","admin_id":"1","types":"Unit Test-2"}]`

So can anyone please help me how to pass this("10th") data to getclass?

I know that the data here i get is a char. But i don't get an option to get this from json object. The error I get is:

`dataorg.json.jsonexception No value for class_name`

but my json output is:`[{"classname":"10th"}]`

So please help me how to pass data to this? And please be specific, please write some code. It's better and easier way to understand. If anyone wants to see the whole code please ask me, i'll definitely update my question.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show us what the input JSON looks like, and tell us what you want `getclass` to contain.  Right now, it seems like you have the "10th" as the value of that JSON field, and (naturally) that's what gets read into `getclass`.

Comment: can u provide the json link? is there any error u getting and show that error also

Comment: @StephenC the input json looks like this: [{"class_name":"10th"}]. Please help me this is very important for me

Comment: no i'm not getting any sort of error. But the value is not getting passed to getclass. I get the json output from a php code.

Comment: you are doing right, i dont think there might be any error in your code.because same way i have done in my project and it works perfectly. can u prvoide the link?

Comment: Here it is clear that we cannot pass data like "10th" to a string. My question was how to pass that data to a string? If it is successful for you.. please post your code, so that i can learn something from yours.

Comment: why we can't pass 10th? can u elaborate more?

Comment: @sulemankhan - Java has no problems assigning `"10th"` to a String.  What makes you think that it doesn't work?  Are you getting an exception?  A compilation error?

Comment: oh...! I got an exception. dataorg.json.jsonexception No value for class_name.

Comment: @StephenC please check my question now. I've updated it with the error

Comment: There is no problem with your code. You sure it is class_name not classname though (You used that in your question). Print out using Log.I(json_data.toString()) to see if you are getting the right data.

Comment: @Edison you are absolutely correct. The data is not getting passed to it. But my php file is showing the whole output. Can u please help me regarding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input JSON actually consists of an array of 4 object of three different kinds.  The object containing the "classname" field is the 2nd object.

However, your code is assuming that all of the objects in the array have the same kind, and that they all have a "classname" field.  That is what is causing your exception.

Look carefully at the structure of the JSON objects, and make sure that your Java code matches that structure.

Comment: you are absolutely correct. Can you please help me how to handle the multiple json outputs in android. Can you please give me a sample. Actually this was my next question.

Comment: @sulemankhan - why do you need code?  This is **simple** Java programming.  If you can't figure out how to do it, you should do a Java tutorial and learn the language.